# Why are my SATA HDDs so slow?

Tags: hard-drive, sata, performance

I run the HDD benchmark in Everest for my 3 SATA2 HDDs and I got around 100-120MB/s linear read speed. The cache test did give me around 200MB/s but it's still far beyond the promised 300MB/s+.

Does anyone know what may be hapening?! I've looked that the jumpers are set to SATA2 and I've looked at the settings in the BIOS and have also made sure that caching is enabled in the policy tab in the Disk Management app.

I'm really baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The cache test did give me around 200MB/s but it's still far beyond the promised 300MB/s+.

That's the controller speed, not hard drive speed. The hard drive speeds are pretty good and nothing to be scoffed at.

Comment: I was getting rather worried. Thanks! :-)

Comment: So why is the cache test (burst speed) 100MB/s slower than advertised?

Comment: @Moab Advertised speeds will always differ from real world tests for various reasons - slow controller, bottlenecks elsewhere, different set of config used on test machines et al